# Java crashes the whole machine / Ubuntu 21.04 / intel Rocket lake CPU

Tags: java, crash, 21.04, microcode

Folks,
I received a brand-new computer with a Z590M motherboard and a 11th gen core i7 (aka Rocket Lake) CPU last week. Installed Hirsute Hippo and started importing my java/scala/kotlin projects.

But when I do "gradle clean" or "mvn compile", the whole machine crashes. And it crashes really hard, there isn't even any stack trace anywhere, and I find no traces of this in /var/crash, /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/syslog. Same thing if I launch Intellij Idea or Android Studio: the machine reboots and there are no traces of any crash in logs anywhere. If I do ctrl+alt+f3 and do a "mvn compile", the same thing happens, so I don't think this is related to any GUI stuff. All other stuff on the computer runs just fine: Firefox/thunderbird, shell, LibreOffice, ... And minor attempts at compiling and running a 20-line java file setting up a swing frame with a button on it, works, both for compilation and for running. So I assume that the crash is only triggered by something a bit more complicated in the java ecosystem.

I have googled around and found this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2310. Could Rocket Lake be suffering from a defect like the one in Ice Lake? I don't see a solution for Ubuntu on that page, btw.

I have tried to update the intel microcode on the machine, but to no avail. Apt claims I'm on the newest version (3.20201110.0ubuntu1). According to https://pkgs.org/search/?q=microcode, that is indeed the newest version, although this download page: https://pkgs.org/download/intel-microcode indicates (on grey background at the bottom) that Intel has released newer versions.

Could I be right in believing that the microcode could be involved in this? I find it odd that noone has reported this anywhere, so I'm uncertain. And since the machine has no sign of any crash in the places I mentioned above, how should I report this or track the bug further?

Comment: Suggest you review [this Rocket Lake user](https://askubuntu.com/users/1225257/rsr911) activity, and in particular try the oem kernel he mentions, 5.10.0-1023-oem (20.04b).

Comment: Absolutely up the same alley, but not 100%. I had already seen some of his postings and implemented the i915.force_probe=4c8a trick ... 

But this is different. I'm not having monitor problems, I'm experiencing a complete computer reboot. Installing the 5.10 oem kernel didn't change anything, and I also tried the newest one I could find, 5.13-rc, but also that one had the same crashes.

Weird and frustrating.

Comment: As a very long shot, and just as a test, try disabling turbo CPU frequencies. `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` Why? maybe some timing or race condition that only appears with these newer so fast processors.

Comment: Brilliant, Doug, that worked! Thanks a million! (And now, I wonder what I am missing and how I will know when not to do this anymore because Ubuntu has caught up). I noticed that this setting takes immediate effect and did not survive a reboot. Do you know where I can read about it, in order to fully understand what I am doing now?

Comment: Yes, I wonder also. You can disable turbo in BIOS, to make it "sticky" across re-boots. All it does is prevent your CPUs from going into the turbo frequency area. You could also experiment with limiting the maximum frequency via [two other methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335639/ubuntu-how-to-change-cpu-max-mhz/1335646#1335646).